# c# if string equals database table

Tags: c#, mysql, getstring

I am trying to have `c#` look to see if the database `table` equals what i am asking it to equal to open a specific form here is one way i am try doing it

```
void getsformat()
    {
        string constring = @"server=host;userid=user;password=pass";
        string Query = "select colum from table where callsign= '" + listBox1.SelectedItem + "'";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string sfName = myReader.GetString("sformat");
              }  
            if (sfName == "stworld")
            {
                sendtext = textBox1.Text;
                Form3 f3 = new Form3();
                 f3.Location = new Point(this.Top);

                f3.ShowDialog();  
            }
            else if (sfName == "seperate")
            {
                sendtext = textBox1.Text;
                Form3 f4 = new Form3();
                f4.Location = new Point(this.Top);

                f4.ShowDialog();  
            }


            conDataBase.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

and the othere way with the "while myreader "end quote after the "if" statement

```
void getsformat()
    {
        string constring = @"server=host;userid=user;password=pass";
        string Query = "select colum from table where callsign= '" + listBox1.SelectedItem + "'";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string sfName = myReader.GetString("sformat");

            if (sfName == "stworld")
            {
                sendtext = textBox1.Text;
                Form3 f3 = new Form3();
                f3.Location = new Point(this.Top);

                f3.ShowDialog();  
            }
            else if (sfName == "seperate")
            {
                sendtext = textBox1.Text;
                Form3 f4 = new Form3();
                 f4.Location = new Point(this.Top);

                f4.ShowDialog();  
            }

            }
            conDataBase.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

i cannot get either of them to work . Any help would be apreciated
thank you in advanced

Comment: How do they not work? What should they do, what do they do? Are there errors, or just no data? And NEVER concatenate strings into SQL queries. Use parameters.

Comment: it only opens one form trying to open different forms on the outcome of the sformat

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have the connection string setup properly. 
This:

```
string constring = @"server=host;userid=user;password=pass";
```

Should have the relevant info

```
string constring = @"server=localhost\SQL2008;userid=myusername;password=mypass";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement change it to

```
listbox1.selecteditem.tostring();
```

Comment: that did not work everything i try only uses 1 form i cant get and if statement to work to use different forms on differnet outputs

Comment: are you trying to pass a value from one form to another?

Comment: i kept calling form 3 and it shoulda been the next form i wanted it to go to

Comment: i get ahead of myself sometimes